# How to get json data from server using Volley

Tags: php, android, server, android-volley

i have used volley and get a json data from server. it works well
but when i get a data from server, at android studio log, The data is well received in the form of json. like this

{"read":[{"id":"pp","time":"3","content":"3"},{"id":"pp","time":"22","content":"2"},{"id":"pp","time":"11","content":"1"},{"id":"z","time":"12.12","content":"chest again!"}],"success":"1"}

but i typed server url(when php code exist) at browser and get in there, there is no data from db just shows like

{"read":[],"success":"1"}

here is the java code

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_list, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                System.out.println(response);
                Log.e(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                    if (success.equals("1")) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String id = object.getString("id").trim();
                            String time = object.getString("time").trim();
                            String content = object.getString("content").trim();

                            adapter.addItem(id, time, content);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(listActivity.this, "Error Reading Detail : " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(listActivity.this, "Error Reading Detail : " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("gymName", gymName);

                return params;
            }
           };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

here is the php code on server

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "db", "pw", "user");
    mysqli_query($con,'SET NAMES utf8');

    $gymName = $_POST["gymName"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test where gymName = '$gymName' ORDER BY num desc";
    $response = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $result = array();
    $result['read'] = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)){
        $h['id'] = $row['id'];
        $h['time'] = $row['time'];
        $h['content'] = $row['content'];

        array_push($result['read'], $h);
    }

    $result['success'] = "1";
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

why this happen? plz help

i think in php code, get data from db and implement echo json_encode, should'n be shown db data in URL? i think browser shows json data and android get those shown data Am i wrong?. i just curious how to get a json data from server to android studio

Comment: For me it is unclear what your problem is. First you say that the data is well received. And then that you type something which spoils it. I have no idea why you type and what you type where and why you cannot use tje json text that you received well.

Comment: $gymName variable is a post data variable. I think you need a post data in url to see the data in browser.

Comment: i think in php code, get data from db and implement echo json_encode, should'n be shown db data in URL? i think browser shows json data and android get those shown data Am i wrong?. i just curious how to get a json data from server to android studio